# What being Magento developer mean in practice?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento2

Am I correct that new magento developer spends firsts months mainly for understanding Magento **structure** (all pieces of puzzle) than programming custom classes?

and

being good Magento developer is more about **how you move around** this complicated architecture and how well you **insert these pieces in correct places** than just writing custom classes (algoritms) like in "usually PHP projects" written in Symfony framework f.e.?

*(I know this not place for this kind of questions, but other magento comunities are death. I will remove this question tomorrow if no reply*)

Answer (score 3):

The learning curve of Magento can be pretty high, especially if you are new to the framework.  In general you can take online courses to learn the basics, read the docs for clarification and follow other developers to stay abreast of practices used.

The fundamentals should only take a week or two to get down; and really, there is nothing earth shattering about how Magento is developed or what patterns it's using.  Truly understanding how each element comes together to build a page or fulfill a request is going to take time and attention.  There is no better teacher than experience.

If you want high quality reusable code that requires minimal maintenance between versions of Magento, you will invest the time to really learn where files go, how to properly add features and use plugins to modify existing functionality.  If you just want to throw something together and not care about how well it functions, you can still develop a simple module in a day.

So in practice, for me at least, to be a Magento developer is to be active in the community, follow well known developers and businesses, read the documentation often, attend the online trainings, take extra time to really think critically about how your module will work and interact with the core, and follow all the guidelines as laid out by the Magento core team.